# UWP: How to send USSD request. (Get exception, when call SendMessageAndGetReplyAsync)

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

please help me with sending ussd request.

```
IReadOnlyList<string> networkAccIds = MobileBroadbandAccount.AvailableNetworkAccountIds;
if (networkAccIds.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}
string networkAccountId = networkAccIds[0];
UssdSession session = UssdSession.CreateFromNetworkAccountId(networkAccIds[0]);
```

2 sim card installed in my phone. But `networkAccIds.Count` always zero. What's my mistake?

#### update 1:

Thanks *[Jerry Li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112857/6307007)*. I got the network identifiers. I have a new problem. When I do:

```
UssdReply reply = await session.SendMessageAndGetReplyAsync(new UssdMessage("*100#"));
```

I get exception:

Unexpected exception occured: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070032): The request is not supported.

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()


   at uwp_1.MainPage.<GetBalance>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Why do I get exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2 sim card installed in my phone. But networkAccIds.Count always zero. What's my mistake?

You are accessing **privileged APIs** ([UssdSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.networkoperators.ussdsession.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [MobileBroadbandAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207353)) used by mobile broadband operators. It requires a [special-use capability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#special-and-restricted-capabilities) to be declared in **package manifest:**

```
<Capabilities>
  <r:Capability Name="cellularDeviceIdentity"/>
  <r:Capability Name="cellularDeviceControl"/>
  <r:Capability Name="cellularMessaging"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Please make sure you have declared the corresponding [special-use capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#special-and-restricted-capabilities) in package manifest. And the [Mobile broadband sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MobileBroadband) which shows how to use the Mobile Broadband Networking API is for your reference.

**In addition:**

Your app will work and you can test it on your phone, but it will not pass WACK (Windows App Certification Kit) because it uses a [special-use capability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#special-and-restricted-capabilities). This kind of apps can be used in Company app(Don’t need to publish to Windows Store), MS internal or OEM/partner.

Comment: Thank you, but I have new problem. I have exception, when I call the method SendMessageAndGetReplyAsync.

Comment: You are welcome :)  About the new exception, you were not calling the method [SendMessageAndGetReplyAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.networkoperators.ussdsession.sendmessageandgetreplyasync.aspx) properly: `UssdReply reply = await session.SendMessageAndGetReplyAsync(new UssdMessage("*100#")); UssdResultCode code = reply.ResultCode;` And the [USSD protocol sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/UssdProtcol) is for your reference.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your problem, I've the exact same problem.